# writing program in batch script for a editing tool?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My assignment is to create a editing tool that saves before editing. What I need to do is to make the user enter filename. If the file exists in the directory, it should make a backup with an extension of .bak. in the directory and then go on to editing it. If it doesn't exist, then it wont create a back up

Here's what I've done but I'm unsure if this is correct:

```
:: turn the echo off
@echo off
:: ask the user to enter a filename then store it in a variable FILE 
set /p FILE= What File Do You Wish to Edit? 
:: check if the FILE exists 
if EXIST %FILE (
:: back it up 
copy %A%A.bak) 
:: to open file use notepad 
notepad %A
```

Comment: Never use the `::`-style comments (which are actually wrongly formatted jump labels) in parenthesised code blocks as they may lead to unexpected behaviour; use `rem` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You have one of 2 choices.

```
@echo off
set /p "FILE=What File Do You Wish to Edit? "
if EXIST %FILE% (
        copy "%FILE%" "%FILE%.bak"
        notepad "%FILE%"
   ) else (
        echo Sorry, "%FILE%" does not exist.
)
```

The above will check if the file exists, then create a copy adding a `bak` extension after the current extension i.e `file.txt.bak`

This example uses a `for` loop to create the filename with a new extension.

```
@echo off
set /p "FILE=What File Do You Wish to Edit? "
for %%i in (%FILE%) do if exist %FILE% (
        copy "%%~ni" "%%~ni.bak"
        notepad "%FILE%"
   ) else (
        echo Sorry, "%FILE%" does not exist.
)
```

To understand more about what was done here, open `cmd` and get the help files for the following commands:

- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`